# Minimum Longest Distance Algorithm, Problems with implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm

i'm trying to implement an algorithm, that takes a route with several distances and the number of days that someone has time to ^go this route. The algorithm should calculate the minimum longest distance per day.

I already asked in Mathematics because I needed help with finding the mathematical function. There you can find an example to understand easier what I mean. [See Here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817090/calculate-shortest-maximum-length-of-stages-for-given-distances-and-number-of-st)

I tried to implement the proposed recursive function:

```
Md(e1,…,en) = min{Md(e1,…,e′n−1), max{M d−1(e1,…,en−1), en}}
```

Where `Md(e1,…,en)` is the minimum of the longest stage over all groupings, `e1-en` are the distances and `Md` is the function on day `d` with the assumption  that `Md(e1,e2,…,en)=max{e1,…,en}` if `d≥n`

My try to implement this is here:

```
private static int recursiveMin(int[] teilstrecken, int days)
    {

        List<int> tempList1 = new List<int>(teilstrecken);
        int last = tempList1.Last();
        tempList1.Remove(tempList1.Last());
        int vorletzter = tempList1.Last();
        List<int> tempList2 = new List<int>(teilstrecken);
        tempList1.Remove(tempList1.Last());
        tempList1.Add(last + vorletzter);
        tempList2.Remove(tempList2.Last());

        int[] array1 = tempList1.ToArray();
        int[] array2 = tempList2.ToArray();

        if (nEtappen >= teilstrecken.Length)
        {
            return array1.Max();
        }

        return Math.Min(recursiveMin(array1, days), Math.Max(recursiveMin(array2, days-1), last));
    }
```

But this does not return what I want.
One Example:

`{64, 23, 56, 34, 23, 65, 28}` in 3 Days should return 113 but instead returns 90.

Now I'm asking if I did a mistake in the implementation or if the formula was wrong in the begining.
Anyone an idea? Thanks in forward.

Comment: Your last call to `recursiveMin` should specify `days - 1`.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right, but this now leads to an index out of range.

Comment: As a general advice: choose ONE language for your variables. For help in communities like SO, english would be the best choice obviously. Also, find names which describe the variable. Names like "array1", "tempList1" etc. make understanding the code quite hard for others now and for yourself in 2 months too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please please please name variables so that you or someone else will understand what they mean in 6 months time ;)

Think the method wasn't quite right, it was easier to redo it here:

```
private static int recursiveMin(int[] distances, int days) {
      // check for edge cases (single distance or one day)
      if(distances.length == 1) {
         return distances[0];
      }
      if(days == 1) {
         int sum = 0;
         for(int i=0;i<distances.length;i++) {
            sum += distances[i];
         }
         return sum;
      }

      // get the last distance
      int last = distances[distances.length - 1];

      // create the reduced array
      int[] oneLess = new int[distances.length - 1];
      for(int i=0;i<oneLess.length;i++) {
         oneLess[i] = distances[i];
      }

      // this is the max{M d−1(e1,…,en−1), en} part
      int right = Math.max( recursiveMin( oneLess, days - 1 ), last );

      // now use the reduced array again but add the last value on at the end
      oneLess[oneLess.length - 1] += last;

      // this is the Md(e1,…,e′n−1) part
      int left = recursiveMin( oneLess, days );

      return Math.min( left, right );
   }
```

It's done it in Java but am sure it's a fairly quick process to translate it to C# if you wanted. It produces the expected values for the two examples, but hasn't been tested for anything else, so make sure to test it before expecting it to work for every case!